# Realtime outlier detection using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, outliers

New to python. Am from a nodejs background.

Nodejs has npm packages (outlier/outliers etc) where I just need to call the detectOutlier function and it returns the value. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/outlier)

Am trying to do the same in python, since node is not a good choice for computationally heavy processing.

In python, I could find libraries like pyod which consume csv files. My data is in mongodb.

How do I detect outliers in realtime data (mongodb)?

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of this python library: https://pypi.org/project/outlier-detector/ which detects outliers in small datasets or in data moving windows, based on Dixon's method.

I don't think there's something consuming directly data from MongoDB, however you may apply one of the tools in the library to analyze your data.

If more help required, please extend the question with more details and maybe a piece of code.

Best